# MATERIAL-TABLE: How do I make certain cells have drop-down menus on clicking an Edit Action button?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, material-table

I want to create the following:

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFShO.png)

Here as you can see Assigned Location and Put-Away Location cells have drop-down menus to select values from once the Edit Action Button is clicked.

Here's what I have tried:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Task ID",
    field: "taskId",
    editable: "never",
    filtering: true,
    queryParam: "taskId",
  },
  {
    title: "Shipment",
    field: "shipment",
    editable: "never",
    filtering: true,
    queryParam: "shipment",
  },
  {
    title: "Assigned Agent",
    field: "assignedAgent",
    filtering: true,
    queryParam: "assigned_agent",
    lookup: { 34: "AGENT X", 63: "AGENT Y" },
  },
  {
    title: "Put Away Location",
    field: "location",
    filtering: true,
    queryParam: "location",
    lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" },
  },
];

<MaterialTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        onRowClick={(event, rowData) => {
          history.push(`/return-to-seller-tasks/${rowData?.taskId}`, {
            taskId: rowData?.taskId,
          });
        }}
        editable={{
          onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                const dataUpdate = [...data];
                const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                dataUpdate[index] = newData;
                //  setData([...dataUpdate]);

                resolve();
              }, 1000);
            }),
        }}
/>
```

Currently the look up approach I have tried is also adding the drop-down menu to the search filter which I do not want. Please guide me.